# highlight invalid input, component.valid always valid but binding works

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I just learnt about the [component.valid](https://blog.oio.de/2013/07/30/how-to-highlight-invalid-components-in-jsf/) EL expression and I'm having some trouble with it. My component is always valid when I use `component.valid` instead of binding the component and using the bound name :

This works:

```
    <h:inputText required="true" binding="#{textIn}" value="#{testBean.number}" style="#{textIn.valid ? 'border:1px solid green;' : 'border:1px solid red;'}">
        <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="3"></f:validateDoubleRange>
    </h:inputText>
```

Without the binding and using component.valid the component is always valid :

```
    <h:inputText required="true" value="#{testBean.number}" style="#{component.valid ? 'border:1px solid green;' : 'border:1px solid red;'}">
        <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="3"></f:validateDoubleRange>
    </h:inputText>
```

What's wrong with this ? It's really a deal breaker for me because I have to type one more attribute and I can only type that much..

Comment: Try updating/rendering the entire form after submit.

Comment: That trick is taken over from [my blog](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html). JSF utility library OmniFaces offers a [single tag](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) which transparently does all the necessary magic.

Comment: @KishorP it works well now, thanks. I've no idea why it worked at some point with the binding attribute without any update, but it doesn't seem to work today if I don't update so I'll assume there was probably a mistake in my code(maybe I did use update without seeing it but yeah I doubt it).

Comment: @BalusC I saw in your blog you wrote in your css #{resource..} to locate a resource. When reading this I was exited and tried #{aBean.color} in my css. Unfortunately it didn't work. Is it reserved to implicit component ? As for the omnifaces tag, I will be blunt but it doesn't really save much time. I'll use omnifaces in the future but for now I think it abstract things I need to know to understand the jsf framework well.

Comment: Presence of EL in CSS is checked only once per CSS file application wide. So if you were editing an existing CSS file without EL without restarting the application, you need to restart the application. Learning/hobbying/fiddling/practicing around with JSF is a very good reason to not use OmniFaces yet :)

Comment: @BalusC Thank you. I was wondering when I was driving the other day, don't answer if it's inappropriate but how do you think? with images ? you see words, in java ?

Comment: @BalusC That doesn't answer much :D. Anyway I'll leave it at that. I think in sound that's why I had an hard time understanding.

Comment: :) At least definitely not with sound. I also can't imagine how the hearing could think with that, I find sound far too disturbing. When I think, I mostly just ... think logically.

Comment: @Ced : Ok ill add that as an answer. You are asking BalusC how he thinks? He doesn't need to, ideas just flow out of his brains like water :) he has inspired lots of people including me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update or render the entire `h:form` after submission.
This will re evaluate the el expression bound to `style` attribute.